# Gson deserialize null pointer in released apk

Tags: android, json, debugging, gson, release

I'm writing an Android app need using gson to deserialize the json string:

```
{
    "reply_code": 001,
    "userinfo": {
        "username": "002",
        "userip": 003
    }
}
```

so I create two classes:

```
public class ReturnData {
    public String reply_code;
    public userinfo userinfo;
}

public class userinfo {
    public String username;
    public String userip;
}
```

finally, my Java code in MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Context context= MainActivity.this;

    //Test JSON
    String JSON="{\"reply_code\": 001,\"userinfo\": {\"username\": \"002\",\"userip\": 003}}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ReturnData returnData=gson.fromJson(JSON,ReturnData.class);

    if(returnData.reply_code==null)
        Toast.makeText(context,"isNULL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(context,"notNULL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

What made me confused is, when I debug the app,it ran well and output "notNULL".I can see the every attribution of the object has been deserialized properly.
However,when I generated released apk from Android Studio and run apk on phone,it output "isNULL",the json resolution failed！

Who can tell me what happened?!

PS:build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.padeoe.autoconnect"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "2.1.4"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('src/gson-2.3.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: @No Name  do you mean build.gradle?I have uploaded now.

Comment: no show 'proguard-android.txt' file

Comment: Sorry,where can I find proguard-android.txt in Android Studio?I cannot find it.Thank you!

Comment: I just found if I removed"minifyEnabled true" in build.gradle,the problem was solved!!!but why?!

Comment: yah thats what whenerver you are  applying at that time it wont work because gson internally uses reflection

Comment: minfy = false means progaurd will not be applied

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have ProGuard enabled in your `release` build type - `minifyEnabled true`. It obfuscates the code by changing class/variable names.

You should annotate your class properties, so Gson knows what to look for:

```
public class ReturnData {
    @SerializedName("reply_code")
    public String reply_code;
    @SerializedName("userinfo")
    public userinfo userinfo;
}

public class userinfo {
    @SerializedName("username")
    public String username;
    @SerializedName("userip")
    public String userip;
}
```

This way Gson won't look at the properties' names, but will look at `@SerializedName` annotation.

Comment: This answer took WAAAAY to long to find. Well done @Egor N.

Comment: Just FYI, the code in your example says `@SerialiazedName`. It's supposed to be `@SerializedName`

Comment: Thanks to you because it saved my whole day

Comment: Has been searching for a way to fix this bug for 2 days. Great thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I use @SerializedName in my class yet, in my case when using toJson() it only deserialized the 1st key/value pair and discarded the rest, I

Comment: I did with serializeName but still it return blanck object. Someone plz reply.

String cameraResponseJson = new Gson().newBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create().toJson(mCameraResponse);

This is how I converting pojo to JSON

Comment: This did not help , only solution is exclude  Serialized name from obfuscation. -keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
   @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
 }

Answer (score 31):

You can either use `@SerializedName` as mentioned by @Egor N or you may add the Gson classes to the `proguard-rules.pro` by using

```
-keep class com.packageName.yourGsonClassName
```

The latter has the following advantages over the former:

- when writing your code you can put all your Gson class in a folder and keep all of them from obfuscation using the following, which saves a lot of coding:

  ```
  -keep class com.packageName.gsonFolder.** { *; }
  ```
- Adding `@SerializedName` to each field in Gson classes is not only time-consuming especially in large projects with lots of Gson files but also increases the possibility of mistakes entering the code, if the argument in the `@SerializedName` is different from the field name.
- If any other methods, such as getter or setter methods are used in the Gson class, they may also get obfuscated. Not using `@SerializedName` for these methods causes crash in runtime due to conflict in names.

Comment: For me, it works after adding additional info **private fields** like this
-keep class com.packageName.yourGsonClassName{
        private <fields>;
}

Answer (score 0):

> Add This Lines  inside pro-guard file

```
    ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```